# Prestashop to Amazon Product Import through XML

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, product, prestashop-1.5, amazon-mws

I am using Third party Module to synchronize my products to Amazon.in using Amazon Marketplace web Service (Amazon MWS).
I send the following Product Feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>A23HJ74Y8N7IZI</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110</SKU>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>parent</Parentage>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110-DGM-L</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>EAN</Type>
        <Value>8903189246745</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110 - Dark Grey Melange, L</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110-DGM-L</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <Size>Large</Size>
            <Color>Dark Grey Melange</Color>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <ColorMap>Multi-Coloured</ColorMap>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <SizeMap>Large</SizeMap>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>3</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110-DGM-S</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>EAN</Type>
        <Value>8903189246738</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110 - Dark Grey Melange, S</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110-DGM-S</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <Size>Small</Size>
            <Color>Dark Grey Melange</Color>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <ColorMap>Multi-Coloured</ColorMap>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <SizeMap>Small</SizeMap>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>4</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110-DGM-XL</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>EAN</Type>
        <Value>8903189246721</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110 - Dark Grey Melange, XL</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110-DGM-XL</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <Size>X-Large</Size>
            <Color>Dark Grey Melange</Color>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <ColorMap>Multi-Coloured</ColorMap>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <SizeMap>X-Large</SizeMap>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>5</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110-DGM-M</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>EAN</Type>
        <Value>8903189246714</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110 - Dark Grey Melange, M</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110-DGM-M</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <Size>Medium</Size>
            <Color>Dark Grey Melange</Color>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <ColorMap>Multi-Coloured</ColorMap>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <SizeMap>Medium</SizeMap>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>6</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
      <SKU>MSL110-DGM-XXL</SKU>
      <StandardProductID>
        <Type>EAN</Type>
        <Value>8903189246707</Value>
      </StandardProductID>
      <Condition>
        <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
      </Condition>
      <DescriptionData>
        <Title>Boerandfitch - Grey Milange Boxer Shorts - MSL110 - Dark Grey Melange, XXL</Title>
        <Brand>Boerandfitch</Brand>
        <Description>97% cotton ,3% polyester&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Dark Grey Melange colour, Regular fit&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Wash dark colour seperately&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
 Do not Iron on applique. Reverse Iron&#13;&lt;br /&gt;
Machine wash or hand wash using a mild detergent</Description>
        <BulletPoint>Constructed in cotton fine fleece</BulletPoint>
        <Manufacturer>Boerandfitch</Manufacturer>
        <MfrPartNumber>MSL110-DGM-XXL</MfrPartNumber>
        <SearchTerms>online shopping shorts knitted trackpant track sho</SearchTerms>
        <SearchTerms>bottom melange shorts cotton shorts fire bird shor</SearchTerms>
      </DescriptionData>
      <ProductData>
        <Clothing>
          <VariationData>
            <Parentage>child</Parentage>
            <Size>XX-Large</Size>
            <Color>Dark Grey Melange</Color>
            <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
          </VariationData>
          <ClassificationData>
            <ClothingType>Sleepwear</ClothingType>
            <Department>Men</Department>
            <StyleKeywords>Relaxed</StyleKeywords>
            <ColorMap>Multi-Coloured</ColorMap>
            <MaterialComposition>Cotton</MaterialComposition>
            <InnerMaterial>Cotton</InnerMaterial>
            <OuterMaterial>Cotton</OuterMaterial>
            <Season>Spring-Summer</Season>
            <SizeMap>XX-Large</SizeMap>
            <CollectionName>Spring-Summer 14</CollectionName>
          </ClassificationData>
        </Clothing>
      </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

**i get this error in report return :**

---

Product Feed - ID: 10242392398
Entry   Result
Entries Processed   6
Entries Successful  1
Entries with Error  5
Entries with Warning    1

Error 8008: SKU: MSL110 - We cannot recognize your child SKU: [MSL110]. For help on how to proceed,

Error 8008: SKU: MSL110 - We cannot recognize your child SKU: [MSL110]. For help on how to proceed

Error 8008: SKU: MSL110 - We cannot recognize your child SKU: [MSL110]. For help on how to proceed

Error 8008: SKU: MSL110 - We cannot recognize your child SKU: [MSL110]. For help on how to proceed

Error 8008: SKU: MSL110 - We cannot recognize your child SKU: [MSL110]. For help on how to proceed

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110 - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-L - A value is required for the "department_name" field.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-L - A value is required for the "material_type" field.

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110-DGM-L - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-S - A value is required for the "department_name" field.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-S - A value is required for the "material_type" field.

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110-DGM-S - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XL - A value is required for the "department_name" field.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XL - A value is required for the "material_type" field.

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XL - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-M - A value is required for the "department_name" field.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-M - A value is required for the "material_type" field.

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110-DGM-M - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XXL - A value is required for the "department_name" field.

Error 99001: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XXL - A value is required for the "material_type" field.

Error 99042: SKU: MSL110-DGM-XXL - A value was not provided for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please provide a value for "recommended_browse_nodes". Please use the Product Classifier or download the category-specific Browse Tree Guide from Seller Help to see a list of valid "recommended_browse_nodes" values. This information tells Amazon where your product should be classified and affects how easily customers can find your product.

---

Can you explain me how to I solve this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

One thing up front: You don't say which third party module you are using with PrestaShop, so we have to take wild guesses as to what that actually does and how to change its behavior.

You are sending one parent SKU (MSL110) and five children (MWS110-DGM-S, -M, -L, -XL and -XXL). MWS reports it has successfully processed one of those six. I assume it is the parent product, please check in Seller Central if that is the case.

Your feed doesn't validate with the XSDs I've got. Mine do not allow `CollectionName`, but may be it is outdated. The feed seems to have passed the validation stage of the MWS feed processing though, so I guess it is fine with Amazon anyways.

You are getting multiple errors:

1. **Error 8008** means Amazon couldn't establish the parent-child link. Since appearantly MWS rejected the five child products to begin with, you should focus on other errors first.
2. **Error 99001** missing "department_name". This probably refers to the XML element `Department` in `ClassificationData`, which you **did** specify.
3. **Error 99001** missing "material_type". This probably refers to the XML element `MaterialAndFabric` in `ClassificationData`, which you **did not** specify.
4. **Error 99042** missing "recommended_browse_nodes". The XML field this refers to is `RecommendedBrowseNode` in `DescriptionData` which you **did not** specify

Steps to solve these:

1. The easiest one is the last error. Get the [Browse Tree Guide](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/btg/apparel_browse_tree_guide.xls), and pick the correct category from the list.
   In your case, the appropriate category seems to be ID 1045710, "Clothing & Accessories/Men/Underwear/Boxers". Put right before your closing `DescriptionData` tag, like this: 
   `...<RecommendedBrowseNode>1045710</RecommendedBrowseNode></DescriptionData>`. This should get rid of error #4.
2. The same Browse Tree Guide shows two additional values in the next column: `department_name:mens AND item_type_keyword:boxer-shorts`. What that means is your ClassificationData should include those two values. Your Department already reads "Mens", but I'd change that to lower case to match the BTG, and see if error #2 goes away. The item type keyword is called `StyleKeywords` in XML and should contain "boxer-shorts".
3. While you're at it, you should also add `MaterialAndFabric`. `<MaterialAndFabric>cotton</MaterialAndFabric>`. This should get rid of error #3.
4. Now you should see all six products in Seller Central, if you do, error #1 is likely to have vanished as well, as it now can create parent-child links since they actually are in the database.